# How run npm on deploy project via git? (hooks/post-receive: npm: command not found)

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, npm, digital-ocean

### Problem

I created a project where configure a server in DigitalOcean with Apache and Git.

For init project on server, I run the following command:

```
cd /var/repo
mkdir project-example.git && cd project-example.git
git init --bare
```

I set up file `post-receive` with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/var/temp/project-example --git-dir=/var/repo/project-example.git checkout -f
cd /var/temp/project-example
npm install
npm run build
rm -rf /var/www/project-example/*
mv -f /var/temp/project-example/build/* /var/www/project-example/
```

When I make a push to server remote via git on machine local, occurs followings errors:

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 4: npm: command not found
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 5: npm: command not found
```

However, accessing server via SSH and execute command:

```
# it works standard
cd /var/repo/project-example.git
source hooks/post-receive
```

### Comments

System Server: Ubuntu 14.04

I installed node via nvm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a git hook runs, it does not necessarily have the same PATH variable set as when you log in via SSH. Try putting the full path to npm in your script when you call it; that should fix things.

**UPDATE (June 7 2019):**

A couple of commenters had issues with node not being found when using the above solution, which made me realize it is not very robust. Rather than put the path in the call to npm itself, you'd be better off adding the necessary path to the script's environment, e.g. if npm (and node) happen to be in `/usr/bin/`, add the following to your script before calling npm:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

In fact, a more robust way to make sure the hook works the same as it does when you are logged in via SSH is to find out what the path is when you are logged in (i.e. the output of `echo $PATH`) and set the path in your hook script accordingly  (of course you may need to omit some user-specific paths, etc.)

Comment: what if I set full path to npm, but I get ..node: command not found?
if I connect with ssh and run the npm command , no problem at all. Maybe git can't fint node in the system some way?

Comment: @subdesign, I'm also stuck on this part, where you able to figure it out? I get "env: node: No such file or directory". I'm also using nvm.

Comment: "Try putting the full path to npm in your script when you call it;" How do you do that?

Comment: @Florian/@DavidTrinh/@subdesign - I updated/improved my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case (node installed with nvm) PATH should be this:
export PATH=$PATH:/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin

Comment: I installed node with nvm, too. Hardcoding a fixed version number into the hook still feels problematic. Is there a way to always use the same version as the npm on the command line does?